# ActiveMQ Artemis call browse method with API

Tags: api, activemq-artemis

I have faces with a problem, when I tried to use an browse() method using API.

[image]

When I try to execute it, it runs well, but the following generated URL does not work. It looks like that:

```
http://10.20.2.23:8161/console/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker="0.0.0.0",component=addresses,address="CMN.DataExchange.TEST.GSH",subcomponent=queues,routing-type="anycast",queue="CMN.DataExchange.TEST.GSH"/browse(java.lang.String)
```

and gives me a request: 
[image]

I am trying to filter it by AMQPriority=1, when I type on interface, it is working. How can I make so that this URL should work ? I tried to werite inside browse(java.lang.String) : AMQPriority=1, but as an response it still give me bad request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer. In the end of the URL, I've just added a slash and right after the slash, typed my filter.

URL looks like that now:

```
http://10.20.2.23:8161/console/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker="0.0.0.0",component=addresses,address="CMN.DataExchange.TEST.GSH",subcomponent=queues,routing-type="anycast",queue="CMN.DataExchange.TEST.GSH"/browse(java.lang.String)/AMQPriotiry=4
```